# Remove the Header and Footer on WooCommerce My-Account for unlogged users

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

In WooCommerce, I wanted to simplify the `My-Account` page by removing the `Header` and `Footer` **only** if the user is not logged in, or if the `My-Account` page is showing the `Login or Register` form.

I wanted the users to focus only on the `Login or Register` form, can it be done using Hook?

Something like;

```
function remove_header_footer(){
  if(!is_user_logged_in() && is_page('my-account')){
     //Remove the header and footer
  }
}
add_action('WHAT-ACTION-TO-USE?', 'remove_header_footer');
```

Comment: I think it depends of your theme, you can use maybe js?

Comment: There is not core hook after the wp_header and wp_footer are called, you might want to test if the user is logged in and if the page is "my-account" directly in your header and footer file.

Answer (score 0):

Find out get_header() and get_footer() in myaccount page. Place those functions inside your conditions.